# How to split a file in spring batch based on no of lines?

Tags: spring-batch, file-read, file-processing

I have a file like this: abc.txt

```
1 fhdfjdkslk
2 jskslsss
3 iowiwjwm
4 jwkwlwo
5 uuwwwmwaa
6 sbnsbshj
7 yywuiwoiw
8 dhdhgsgs
9 sgsgsgs
10 uwuwqmksam
```

I want to split this file using Spring Batch in a configurable way and read the file in a multi-threaded way.

For example if we split by 4 lines.

Thread 1 will process

```
1 fhdfjdkslk
2 jskslsss
3 iowiwjwm
4 jwkwlwo
```

Thread 2 will process

```
5 uuwwwmwaa
6 sbnsbshj
7 yywuiwoiw
8 dhdhgsgs
```

Thread 3 will process

```
9 sgsgsgs
10 uwuwqmksam
```

Finally the output of all the 3 threads will be consolidated in the last step of the Spring Batch job.

I have been able to achieve this if each set contains only 1 line.

How can I achieve this if each set contains multiple lines in Spring Batch ?

Comment: Be careful because a FlatFileItemReader is not thread safe because it maintains state in the form of a ResourceLineReader. Be careful to configure a FlatFileItemReader using an appropriate factory or scope so that it is not shared between threads.

Comment: How big of the file?

Comment: File size around 12GB. Around 10-12 million lines in the file.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own `SystemCommandTasklet`. This tasklet is used to execute a system command. You could use the split command to split the files. Subsequently you can use partitioner to execute the processing of separate files.

More information about this tasklet [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/SystemCommandTasklet.html)